Where the default network kernel parameters for pods come from
I know how to set a pod's kernel parameters but I want to know Where the default network kernel parameters for pods come from.
I tried to look up the answer online, but there is very little information on this subject.Thanks for your help.

Containers use the kernel of the host. They don't have their own kernel, so no own kernel parameters.
If you need different kernel parameters you need to set up VMs for your case.
